# Bracha on Beanitos chips

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

What is the bracha on [Beanitos chips](http://www.beanitos.com/)? Anyone know if it should be more specific (as it contains beans and rice as the primary ingredients)?

Comment: It looks like a bamba snack

Comment: What's the first ingredient?

Comment: @YEZ Whole Navy Beans is first ingredient

Comment: These look tasty! Haven't seen these in my area. Then, again, haven't looked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Beanitos website](http://www.beanitos.com/#faq), Beanitos are made by making a dough out of cooked beans and whole grain rice.  Whole grain rice is a topic of discussion if it is mezonos or ha'adama, but [I was told](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43525/bracha-on-beanitos-chips?noredirect=1#comment112981_43525) that the first ingredient is beans, and rice does not have the halacha of "kol she'yesh bo" (the halacha that even a minority of mezonos takes precedence) which mezonos products of the 5 grains have (S.A. O.C. 208:7).  Therefore, the blessing to discuss would be that of the beans.

Something which is mushed into a jelly or dough-like consistency is the subject of a dispute between the Rambam and other Rishonim, cited in S.A. O.C. 202:7 - the Mechaber codifies the opinion of the Rambam that a food maintains it's blessing even when made into a dough.  The Rama says that even though the primary opinion is that of the Rambam,  it is better to take the other opinion into account and to therefore make shehakol.

The Mishna Berura (202:44) cites the Shulchan Aruch HaRav and Chayei Adam that if the main way to eat this food is through it's being pulverized then it would still get its original blessing.  However, the main way to eat beans is not specifically through this process (or any process of pulverizing it) - it is quite normal to have beans whole, or in pieces.

Therefore, it would seem the appropriate blessing is shehakol.  CYLOR.

Comment: @code613 no joke, I was just at the supermarket and saw Beanitos for the first time!  I considered buying some in honor of this thread.

Comment: beshert? Looks like Beanitos got some good advertising on this forum.